# Difference between setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT) & setSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT))

Tags: java, swing

Consider i have a `JTextField` so there are two option `setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT`) and `setSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT))` like this :

```
JTextField t1 = new JTextField();
JTextField t2 = new JTextField();
t1.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
t2.setSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
```

What is the difference between them, and where should to use each one, and what is the best one?

Comment: You can reuse `Dimension` by doing something like `Dimension normalDimension = new Dimensions(WIDTH, HEIGHT));` From the doc, there doesn't seems to be any more differences.

Comment: It's very unusual for you to need to call `setSize` unless you're writing your own layout manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reuse `Dimension` by doing something like :

```
 Dimension normalDimension = new Dimensions(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
```

So you can re-use that `Dimension` in your code, by calling the `setSize` with the `Dimension` argument.

From the doc, there doesn't seems to be any more differences between both `setSize`.

See [setSize(int,int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setSize(int,%20int)) and [setSize(Dimension)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setSize(java.awt.Dimension))

Comment: Thank you @Marc-Andre for this clarification

Answer (score 2):

Generally no difference at all, as `setSize(Dimension d)` internally invokes `resize(Dimension d)`, which invokes `setSize(int width, int height)`.

And BTW all these methods are declared in `java.awt.Component`, i.e. they are common for wide set of awt classes.

Comment: Thank you @Andremoniy, from your answer i can understand that there are a duplication?

Comment: It is not a duplication. Just convenient way of sending message about size being incapsulated into instance of `Dimension` object. Generally, as @Mark-Andre said in his commentary, this object can be reused

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use the same dimension for two different components (say you had a global dimension for your buttons), then you could create a dimension;

```
private Dimension dimension;

public ClassName() {
    dimension = new Dimension(width, height);
}
```

Then you could reuse the dimension for each component - this would save creating many different dimensions.

Just a tip, good luck!